Is the download from the SoundCloud embedded player not working anymore?
The download from the SoundCloud Iframe is not working anymore. When clicking on the download button, nothing happens. In the Developer Console I can see the error "401 Unauthorized".
It does not work on different sites or browsers but also not on the example site of SoundCloud.
I also tried it via the API but I get the same error.
Is this a known issue or is anyone else experiencing the same problem? The SoundCloud Support has not responded in over a week.
I tried to embed multiple downloadable tracks from different accounts on multiple Websites. I expect the download file to start when clicking on the icon, but nothing happens.
It does not work when I'm logged in into SoundCloud but also not when logged out - which should not be a problem after all, because the download should work on every website no matter if logged in or not.

Yes, can confirm, also getting a 401 for the official examples. So you will probably have to wait for SoundCloud to fix this.

I am having the same problem. I also sent in a request to Soundcloud support 6 days ago and I also have not heard anything from them,
I tried sharing a track on Facebook and there the download worked - but that's not where I need it to work.
I wondered if the newest Wordpress update (6.5.4) on June 5 may not be playing nice with Soundcloud but it sounds like you encountered the problem on other sites besides Wordpress?
